# How to pass variables to the controller in a submit form in Spirng Boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a form with 3 radio buttons, when some radio button is pressed, I want to send to the controller the value of the radio button and an Id variable that I send from the controller to the view.

The HTML view looks like this:

```
 <form id="form" th:action="@{/buscarEmpresa}">
      <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="dia" onclick="submitForm()"> Día
      <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="mes" onclick="submitForm()"> Mes
      <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="ano" onclick="submitForm()"> Año
 </form>
```

When some of the radio buttons is pressed I use the following js code in a `<script>` tag:

```
function submitForm(){
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }
```

The controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/buscarEmpresa")
    public ModelAndView buscarEmpresa(@RequestParam(name = "empresas", required = false) Integer id,
                                      @RequestParam(name="filtro", required = false) String filtro) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.DASHBOARD_3);
        mav.addObject("nombreEmpresa", (empresaRepository.getEmpresaByIdEmpresa(id)).getNombre());
        sendEntradas(mav, id);
        sendSalidas(mav, id);
        mav.addObject("empresas", empresaRepository.findAll());
        mav.addObject("idEmpresa", id);
        return mav;
    }
```

I have tried to change the `th:action` to something like this:

```
th:action="@{/buscarEmpresa?empresas=__${idEmpresas}__}"
```

where `idEmpresas` is the id value I send from the controller and I want to resend it, but when i submit the form, it only send the value of the radio buttons. How can I solve this? I'm using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf as a templates engine.

Comment: Where is the id coming from?  Have you tried adding a hidden input field within your form containing the id?

Comment: First I take the id of a element in a dropdown list and send it to the controller, next I send the id from the controller to a new view in the buscarEmpresa method of above, and I want to resend it to the controller to update the view with the selection of the radio buttons and the id

Comment: Can you add a hidden element for the selected id in your original view?  `<form id="form" ...>
    <input type="hidden" id="empresasId" name="empresasId" value="<empresasId_value_from_select>">
    <input type="radio" name="filtro" ...>
    ...
</form>`

Comment: But if I add the hidden input, at the moment of submit the form it will send the selected radio button AND the id inside that input?

Comment: It worked with the hidden input! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, it should send all data associated within the form.  You may need to add `method="get"` to your form tag to ensure the data is requested with GET and added to URL as query string since you are using `@GetMapping`.  Glad it worked.  Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192334/discussion-between-philip-wrage-and-paul-miranda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your view to embed the selected id within your form as a hidden `input` so it will be returned with the radio selection on each [form submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data):

```html
<form id="form" th:action="@{/buscarEmpresa}">
  <input type="hidden" id="empresasId" name="empresasId" value="<empresasId_value_from_select>">
  <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="dia" onclick="submitForm()"> Día
  <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="mes" onclick="submitForm()"> Mes
  <input type="radio" name="filtro" value="ano" onclick="submitForm()"> Año
</form>
```